# expected comma after getelementptr's type. LLVM

Tags: llvm

```
(1) @str = private constant [13 x i8] c"Hello World\0A\00"
(2) define i32 @main(){
(3) %r2 = getelementptr [13 x i8]* @str, i32 0, i32 0
(4) ret i32 0
(5) }
```

I've got an error error in the line 3: `expected comma after getelementptr's type`. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getelemtptr` expects the type that you are indexing (without the pointer) as it's first argument. In your case that would be `[13 x i8]`, so you probably want to do something like this:

```
%r2 = getelementptr [13 x i8], [13 x i8]* @str, i32 0, i32 0
```